# JSQMessagesViewController Not showing Bubble Image in Chat

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

[image: Not Showing Bubble Image with Messages]

my project in objective-c use JSQMessagesViewController for firebase chat, but bubble images not comes with messages.
JSQMessagesViewController and Firbase integrated via Pods.

Please help me.

Comment: how you integrated JSQMessagesViewController to your project via pod or manual process

Comment: @Vinodh Integrated JSQMessagesViewController via Pods

Comment: did you added - (id<JSQMessageBubbleImageDataSource>)collectionView:(JSQMessagesCollectionView *)collectionView messageBubbleImageDataForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
this methods and return correct image

Comment: yes, i have added this method. and return correct image but Bubble image not comes on messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create method initialise the color for sender and receiver like the code below :

```
  - (JSQMessagesBubbleImage *) setupOutgoingBubble {
    JSQMessagesBubbleImageFactory *bubbleImageFactory = [[JSQMessagesBubbleImageFactory alloc] init];
    JSQMessagesBubbleImage * imgBubble = [bubbleImageFactory outgoingMessagesBubbleImageWithColor:[UIColor blueColor]];//jsq_messageBubbleBlueColor return imgBubble;
    return imgBubble;
}

- (JSQMessagesBubbleImage *) setupIncomingBubble {
    JSQMessagesBubbleImageFactory *bubbleImageFactory = [[JSQMessagesBubbleImageFactory alloc] init];
    JSQMessagesBubbleImage * imgBubble = [bubbleImageFactory outgoingMessagesBubbleImageWithColor:[UIColor greenColor]];//jsq_messageBubbleBlueColor return imgBubble;
    return imgBubble;
}




- (void)setupBubbleColors {
    self.incomingBubbleImageData = [self setupIncomingBubble];
    self.outgoingBubbleImageData = [self setupOutgoingBubble];
}
```

And call above method in `viewDidLoad` like below

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self setupBubbleColors];

}
```

And id `JSQMessageBubbleImageDataSource` delegate return appropriate image like below

```
- (id<JSQMessageBubbleImageDataSource>)collectionView:(JSQMessagesCollectionView *)collectionView
             messageBubbleImageDataForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    Message *message = [_messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"%@", message.type);
    if(message.isOwnMessageValue) {
        return self.outgoingBubbleImageData;
    }
    else return self.incomingBubbleImageData;
}
```

The output will be like below

[image]

Comment: JSQMessagesBubbleImage * imgBubble = [bubbleFactory incomingMessagesBubbleImageWithColor:[UIColor greenColor]];

After execution above code object imgBubble remaining "Nil".

Comment: where you are adding this ? . For me am getting green background image as shared already

Comment: after debugging i found above code didn't call this method :-

- (JSQMessagesBubbleImage *)jsq_messagesBubbleImageWithColor:(UIColor *)color flippedForIncoming:(BOOL)flippedForIncoming

 in JSQMessagesBubbleImageFactory.m class

Comment: have you set self.collectionview.datasoruce = self in viewdidload

Comment: self.collectionview.datasoruce = self;
after adding this code still imgBubble is "nil"

Comment: @implementation ChatVC
{
    JSQMessagesBubbleImage *outgoingBubbleImageView;
    JSQMessagesBubbleImage *incomingBubbleImageView;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    outgoingBubbleImageView = [self setupOutgoingBubble];
    incomingBubbleImageView = [self setupIncomingBubble];
}
- (JSQMessagesBubbleImage *) setupOutgoingBubble
{
    JSQMessagesBubbleImageFactory *bubbleImageFactory;
    JSQMessagesBubbleImage * imgBubble = [bubbleImageFactory outgoingMessagesBubbleImageWithColor:[UIColor blueColor]];//jsq_messageBubbleBlueColor
    
    return imgBubble;
} 
same method for incoming.

Comment: - (id<JSQMessageBubbleImageDataSource>)collectionView:(JSQMessagesCollectionView *)collectionView messageBubbleImageDataForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    JSQMessage *msz = arrMessages[indexPath.item];
    
    if (msz.senderId == self.senderId)
    {
        return outgoingBubbleImageView;
    }
    else
    {
        return incomingBubbleImageView;
    }
}

this method for return bubble image.

Comment: you need to    allocate  JSQMessagesBubbleImageFactory *bubbleImageFactory = [[JSQMessagesBubbleImageFactory alloc] init];
in each methods . please replace in both the methods setupOutgoingBubble and setupIncomingBubble

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172003/discussion-between-vinodh-and-pramod).

Comment: after allocation it works for me. thank you very much for giving me your precious time.

Answer (score 0):

**Download My Chat app demo using firebase N JSQMessagesViewController**

http://www.mediafire.com/file/a8rb2srsbdv643h/firebasechat.zip/file

Comment: why? proper download or not ?

Comment: use mac os on not ?

Comment: use winzip for mac @Pramod. refer download in the media fire download link itself . Problem with media fire website

Comment: give me your email ?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ttjuGjYUgPccJLDCyzd1lXg51_jC7UAH/view?usp=sharing

Comment: check your mail

Comment: your project is in Swift and as i mention in question i have a swift project too of firbase chat with JSQMessagesViewController. and swift project working perfectly but this project is in objective-c and in this project bubble images not comes with messages.